# Try catch handler in async function in asp.net mvc5 behave differently in chrome and IE11

Tags: asp.net-mvc, async-await, internet-explorer-11

I have a asp.net mvc project which uses Entity Framework 6.The index page fetches records in a gridMVC. I have an add a new record button on top to add new record which opens up in a bootstrap modal popup. Everything works fine till the user tries to enter duplicate records. Below is the code where I have done exception handling that whenever the adding fails, it should throw an exception which will display an alert box to user to notify him about adding duplicate records.

```
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Date,PersonelID,OnCallType,Comments")] QnsScheduleNew1 qnsnew1)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.QnsScheduleNew1 .Add(qnsnew1);
        try
        {
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            //return Json(new { RedirectUrl = Url.Action("Index") });
            throw new Exception("Server error");
        }
        return Json(new { RedirectUrl = Url.Action("Index") });
    }
```

in _Create.cshtml, I use ajax form OnFailure event to catch the exception.

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Create", "Queens", new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "validation", HttpMethod = "Post", OnSuccess = "createsuccess",OnFailure="createfailure" }, new { id = "Create" }))
{
    //some code
}
```

And the javascript used is

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap-datepicker3.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function createsuccess(data) {
        if (data.RedirectUrl)
            window.location.href = data.RedirectUrl;
    }
    function createfailure(data) {
        alert("Server error has occured. Are you trying to add duplicate Record!!!");
    }
</script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('.datepicker').datepicker({
            format: "yyyy/mm/dd",
            pickDate: true
        });
        $(".datepicker").datepicker('setValue', new Date());
    });
</script>
```

Everything works perfectly in Chrome, but in IE11 whenever any record is being added, it will alert the user of adding duplicate records.

I have debugged the code when running in IE. It doesn't initially go to the catch block but after returning Json, it will go to the catch block and execute it. Why is this happening? Also debugging showed me that all my methods are hit twice and the manner in which code executes is weird, it can jump off from anything but gives desired results in Chrome than in IE11. I am assuming it is because of the asynchronous way of programming where you can't predict which thread is going to run in which order.

Can someone explain me in detail about this and how to fix this to work in IE11.

Comment: Using Fiddler, are the requests exactly the same between the browsers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about the difference between Chrome and IE11 on this, but perhaps fixing some of the underlying issues will fix that as well.

First, having a `try...catch` where the catch merely raises an exception defeats the entire purpose of using a `try...catch`. Your code would behave exactly the same without it.

Second, your application should not depend on a server error occurring. Server errors should be anomalies indicating a real problem. Returning a 500 on purpose, is not good, unless there was some sort of catastrophic failure on the server. An existing entity is *not* a catastrophic failure.

Generally, according to REST design, you should return a status code that's appropriate. However, there's not really an HTTP status code that applies to an entity already existing. As such, I would say return 200 OK, implying that the request itself was fine, and then in the response body, include some indication of a problem with creating the entity. For example:

```
 try
 {
     await db.SaveChangesAsync();
 }
 catch(Exception e)
 {
     return Json(new { created = false });
 }

 return Json(new { created = true, RedirectUrl = Url.Action("Index") });
```

Then, your `createfailure` function should only concern itself with recovering from a true server error. Your `createsuccess` function should check the value of `created` in the response and either redirect on true or alert on false.

**EDIT**

Technically, there is a special status code for "Created": 201. You could alternatively return the successful response with this status code, and then if the status code is just 200 instead of 201, raise the alert.

Comment: Using  return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest); in catch clause worked. Though I am thinking of using HttpStatusCode.Forbidden as duplicate record is not a bad request..Thanks Chris!!!

Comment: I'm not sure if 403 Forbidden is really accurate either. It's less important that the status code be correct, though, if it's just for your use. If you were creating a public API, things would be different.